# cebe/markdownで、URLをリンクテキストへ自動変換したくない

Tags: php, markdown

「[cebe/markdown](https://github.com/cebe/markdown)」を使用してマークダウンをHTML変換する際、URLテキストがあっても自動的にaタグへ変換しないようにしたいのですが、可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub flavored Markdown では [URL が自動的にハイパーリンクになります](https://help.github.com/articles/autolinked-references-and-urls/)が、Traditional Markdown と Markdown Extra ではそうなりません([例](http://markdown.cebe.cc/try?flavor=default&text=https%3A%2F%2Fja.stackoverflow.com))。

また、cebe/markdown では独自に言語仕様を拡張できるようですので、それを用いて処理を変えることができるかもしれません。[README.md](https://github.com/cebe/markdown) の "Extending the language" に詳細が書かれています。

Comment: リンク提示ありがとうございました。通常リンクはマークダウン仕様だから必ず変換されるけれども、Autolinkは独自拡張なのですね。参考になりました